# Codeigniter and Oracle Query Results not in Sync

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, xampp

I am using Codeigniter on our PHP project that interacts with the Oracle (10g) Database. I have successfully configured Codeigniter to connect and query from the database. However, when I manually run insert/update/delete scripts on the database using Oracle SQL Developer, then check the changes using Codeigniter, it does not recognize the new data.

ie. Say we have a table `TBL_PERSON` that has `ID` and `NAME` columns.
I run an insert statement using Oracle SQL Developer:

```
insert into TBL_PERSON values(1, 'Name1');
```

Then I fetch the data in `TBL_PERSON` through CI:

```
$this->db->get_where('TBL_PERSON', array('ID'=>1));
```

It doesn't return the data that has been recently inserted. I have to restart XAMPP, do refreshes on the page a lot of times before the data appears. But if I use CI to insert the data itself, say

```
$this->db->insert('TBL_PERSON', array('ID'=>1, 'NAME'=>'Name1');
```

then run the fetch code again, it returns the needed data instantly.

Now, I'm not certain where the inconsistency lies: whether it's in Codeigniter or Oracle SQL Developer. If it is in Codeigniter, what is causing this and what should be the correct set-up to prevent this? Does Codeigniter have result caching for Oracle? I've set the Database Caching of CI to OFF already:

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Do you cache the output of the pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have auto commit enabled in SQL Developer? It might be the case the insert statement is not committed immediately.

Comment: You got it! Thanks!!! I didn't bother to look at auto commit of SQL Developer since I'm used to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. The other IT guys attempted everything to

```
INSERT INTO "TABLE" VALUES (1,2,'3'); COMMIT;
```

The `oci_connect` executes the COMMIT after the queries. If you are using a tool like SQL developer, you must execute COMMIT after a query.